# No-Post, BIOS incompatible with CPU?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios

I have an [Asrock H370M Pro4](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/H370M%20Pro4/index.asp#CPU), just purchased, along with some DDR4 RAM and in i5-9600K.

I plugged it all together, and don't get any action when booting.  The fans spin up to full, then down to slow.  CPU fan is working and the CPU power connector is in place.

Nothing appears on screen.  I don't have a speaker to hear beeps, but if I take out the memory altogether, the behaviour changes:t he fans spin up, spin down to slow, then back up to full in a cycle.  This suggests it is trying to POST at least.  I have re-seated everything.  The CPU is making good contact with the fan heatsink.

I stripped back to 1 stick of RAM and CPU, and use the on-board graphics, no disk.

The link above shows that the i5 I have is compatible only with a certain bios level.

I am wondering:

1. Is it possible that a bios incompatibility could lead to no POST at all?
2. If (1) is true, then is there a way to work out what BIOS level it is at without booting?
3. Anything I should try ahead of buying a cheap CPU to test with?

Comment: Could it be only a display issue?

Comment: Are you sure the RAM fits the motherboard?

Comment: @harrymc Yeah, the RAM is on the QVL and in-spec for the i5.

Comment: @DanielK I had a GPU plugged in originally, then switched to the on-die GPU, and then tried another monitor.  Even tried VGA :).

Comment: This is a fresh build so the CPU/mobo/RAM hasn't been tested before, and unfortunately I don't have another system that has the right specs to test any of it.

Comment: The RAM needs to fit the motherboard more than the CPU.

Comment: @harrymc It is in the motherboard QVL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incompatibility with the processor was sufficient to prevent any form of post.  Booting with a compatible CPU worked, and allowed the bios to be flashed, which then let the board boot with the newer CPU.

The bios level on this specific board can be read off a sticker on the cmos.